# How to upload File to Azure Data Lake through Typescript REST CALLS

Tags: node.js, azure, typescript, curl, azure-data-lake

My problem was to upload the file from local directory to Azure Data Lake Store using Typescript only. I then found very useful REST API solution, I tested the REST API to perform all the required operations through postman and they worked fine, I then moved to Typescript to make these calls from typescript. Here is link to that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-rest-api

To make REST CALLS through Typescript I'm using **request-promise** package, that I installed using **npm install request-promise** command. The documentation of this package is provided in this link:- https://github.com/request/request

But i'm able to perform all operations of the REST API i.e; Service-to-Service authentication, Creating Folder, Listing Folders, Rename File, Read File and so on. But i am not able to perform two operations/REST CALLS i.e; **Upload File and Delete File**, every time I make this call it gives **Run Time Exception and error code 501 saying that this operation has not been implemented** though i have tested these operations through Post Man and they work fine that way.

Is there any Access problem or what?

Here is the code of Typescript:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request-promise');
var accessToken; 


getAccessToken();
setTimeout(listFolders, 5000);
setTimeout(renameFile, 5000);
setTimeout(uploadData, 5000);
setTimeout(readData, 5000);


function getAccessToken() {
    request(
    {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/067e9632-ea4c-4ed9-9e6d-
        e294956e284b/oauth2/token',
        form: {
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
            resource: 'https://management.core.windows.net/',
            client_id: 'dc9a4034-b03f-4974-9760-99541137a31c',
            client_secret: 'mJ1Eba+sz0hXQko7gBN3D5WPDVLySCHXg4Mg5F4Ru4s='
        },
        json: true,
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        //Print the Response
        accessToken = body.access_token;
        console.log(accessToken);
    });
}
function uploadData() {
    fs.createReadStream('E:/accessToken.txt')
    .pipe(request({
    method: 'post',
    url:
  'https://bswadls.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/iModelAnalytics/abc.txt?
   op=CREATE',
   json: true,
   headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
    }
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(response.status);
        }
    ));

}

function readData() {
  request(
    {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://bswadls.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/iModelAnalyti
        cs/readFile1.txt?op=OPEN'
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
        },
        json: true,
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        //Print the Response
        console.log("\n\nData = "+body);
        //console.log(response);
    }
);
}

function listFolders() {
    request(
    {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://bswadls.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/
        iModelAnalytics?op=LISTSTATUS',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
        },
        json: true,
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        //Print the Response
        console.log("************List Folders*****************\n ");
        console.log(body);
    }
);
}

function deleteFile() {
    request(
    {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'https://bswadls.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/
        iModelAnalytics/readFile.txt?op=DELETE',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
        },
        json: true,
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        //Print the Response
        console.log("***************Delete File*****************\n ");
        console.log(body);
        console.log('Response= \n');
        console.log(response);
    }
);
}

function renameFile() {
    request(
    {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'https://bswadls.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/
        iModelAnalytics/readFile1.txt?
        op=RENAME&destination=/iModelAnalytics/readFile2.txt',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
        },
        json: true,
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        //Print the Response
        console.log("*************************Delete File*****************\n 
   ");
        console.log(body);
        console.log('Response= \n');
        console.log(response);
    }
);
}
```

This is the error that I get:
[image]

Please share any thoughts regarding this.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try using Postman's 'proxy', and capture the call your node script is making and compare it to the one made from Postman. Perhaps that will reveal the difference:  https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests

Comment: Configured proxy server but nodejs application doesn't go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **PUT** should be used to [upload data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-rest-api#upload-data) whereas **DELETE** should be used to [delete a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-rest-api#delete-a-file).
- Append this `&write=true` to the query string when uploading data via `pipe`.

Try to change the code to:

```
function uploadData() {
    fs.createReadStream('E:/accessToken.txt').pipe(request({
        method: 'put',
        url:'https://bswadls.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/iModelAnalytics/abc.txt?op=CREATE&write=true',
        json: true,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(response.status);
    }));

}

function deleteFile() {
    request({
        method: 'delete',
        url: 'https://bswadls.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/iModelAnalytics/readFile.txt?op=DELETE',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
        },
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        //Print the Response
        console.log("***************Delete File*****************\n ");
        console.log(body);
        console.log('Response= \n');
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much it has solved my problem ! Thanks alot